# ROR changing has_one association to has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new on rails ,actually I am creating a bakery application in which I need to add multiple cookies to one single oven. I am not getting right code for has_many association and how to apply a loop and condition in file having extension of .html.haml

Comment: sorry boss your question is not clear in title u said "ROR changing has_one association to has_many association" but in details there is not explanation for has_one and classed structure. Give the details properly.

Comment: Chirag, the community can probably help you if you can provide a bit more detail about your question. As it stands, we can't determine exactly what your question is. Consider adding a small pseudocode representation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you have two classes

> Oven
>   and
>   Cookie

Cookie Class:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :oven
end
```

Oven Class:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cookies
end
```

Now you want to traverse on all the cookies which belongs to one oven in the view, you can do as following in the view file(html.erb):

```
<% @oven.cookies do |c| %>
   <%= do something %>
<%end %>
```

where `@oven` is instance variable returned from controller.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might helps you [Rails Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)